# 'The term "Clear-RecycleBin" is not recognized' Error in Win 7 PowerShell

Tags: powershell

As the title says, I'm getting this error whenever I run a powershell script. I'm using Windows 7 ultimate 64-bit, Though it works with other PC units that has the same OS, some PC units result in this error. I think that some of them have older versions of Powershell.

Are there other ways to empty the recycle bin using Powershell?

Comment: `Clear-RecycleBin` was introduced in Windows PowerShell 5.0 - have you made sure that Windows Management Framework has been updated (to 5.1) on all your Windows 7 machines?

Comment: How do I update the Windows Management Framework?

Comment: With the [Windows Management Framework installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616)